# How to set global vars from arrays objects to access them outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

`data` is an `object`. It contains a `parse` property, which itself is an `object`, containing a `langLinks` property, which is an Array of objects.

```
data.parse.langlinks.map(function(val){ 
   return val['*'];
});
```

It's fine but I need to be able to read `each` `return val['*'];` outside as this is read within a

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
   data.parse.langlinks.map(function(val){ 
     return val['*'];
  });
  checkLocation();
```

So when I then run the following, won't work.

```
function checkLocation() {
 spacetime[counter].Article.Language.langPrefix.push(val['*']);
```

Trying to `push` it here:

```
            spacetime.push({
                Article : {
                    Title : [],
                    Space : [],
                    Time: {
                        days : [],
                        months : [],
                        years : [],
                        suffixes : []
                    },
                    Language : {
                        TitleLang: [],
                        articleLangId : [],
                        langPrefix : [],
                        langName : [],
                        langLink : []
                    }
                }
            });
```

The array looks output in console:

```
console.log(data.parse.langlinks.map(function(val){ return val["*"] }));
Array(6)
  "Batalla de Tabarsi"
  "Battle of Fort Tabarsi"
  "Batalo de Tabarsi"
  "Batalla del Fuerte de Tabarsí"
  "جنگ قلعه طبرسی"
 "Bataille de Shaykh Tabarsi"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `each return val['*'];` means. Do you simply want to get all the langLinks?

Comment: @mikemaccana just updated the question, basically each of those results must be accessed from outside, yet they are properties of `item` has itself is an `array`

Comment: why are you looping with `$each` when you are doing a `map` over the same variable `data`.

Comment: @rob.m Any thoughts on my answer?

Comment: @mikemaccana checking..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure of the question, but:

```
window.someVariableName = []
var langLinks = _.get(data, 'parse.langLinks');
langLinks.forEach(function(langLink){
  window.someVariableName.push(langLink) 
})
```

Assuming you want to set the global `window.someVariableName` by iterating over `data.parse.langLinks`.

Also:

- `parse` is a bad name for a property - it's a verb so it sounds like a function or method.
- JS uses camelCase for the stdlib and most third party code. TitleCase is only used for Constructors.

Comment: gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined`

Comment: ok works, had to change it to  `var langLinks = data.parse.langlinks.map(function(val){ return val["*"] });;
    langLinks.forEach(function(langLink) {
     someVariableName.push(langLink) ;
    })`

Comment: _ is lodash or underscore, the most common JS library.

Comment: Do you have a property called `*`?

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) method is used in wrong way as data itself will get changed and it wont store any global value with the `return`.

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    var value = item.parse.langlinks.map(function(val){ 
        return val['*'];
    });

    checkLocation(value, i); 
});

function checkLocation(value, counter) {
    spacetime[counter].Article.Language.langPrefix.push(value); 
}
```

Comment: I am not sure where `val['*']` & `counter` are and how they work.

Comment: hang on this looks promising

Comment: if you want to push the whole `langlinks` data, then you might have to add LHS assignment and push that to `checkLocation` method.